# Can not optimize php5-fpm to work without errors

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have installed ngix + php5-fpm. I am happy with it but I can not optimize php5-fpm so that it works without errors. Each fixed error creates a different error.

First I had the the default settings which causet a lot of errors:

```
[04-Jun-2012 03:30:06] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
```

I increased all numbers:

```
pm.max_children = 15
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
;pm.max_requests = 500
```

It caused a different error:

```
[28-Feb-2013 07:45:06] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 18 idle, and 28 total children
```

I increased all numbers again:

```
pm.max_children = 70
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
;pm.max_requests = 500
```

This caused logfile filling up with this:

```
[28-Feb-2013 13:21:55] NOTICE: [pool www] child 21868 exited with code 0 after 4171.293476 seconds from start
[28-Feb-2013 13:21:55] NOTICE: [pool www] child 23962 started
```

I uncommented:

```
pm.max_requests = 500
```

I had the same errors, but not so often -  every 5 minutes:

```
[28-Feb-2013 13:21:55] NOTICE: [pool www] child 21868 exited with code 0 after 4171.293476 seconds from start
[28-Feb-2013 13:21:55] NOTICE: [pool www] child 23962 started
```

I did increase again:

```
pm.max_requests = 1000
```

Now I have this error 2-3 times per hour but it still persists.

I would increase this number again but I feel that my server (websites) work a bit slower than websites hosted on another server with settings: pm.max_children = 15,pm.start_servers = 5, pm.min_spare_servers = 3, pm.max_spare_servers = 5. (probably it's just a network issue, I don't know).

I have searched Google and this website and know how to calculate the pm.max_children (it depends of RAM). But I can not find any information how to calculate:

```
    pm.start_servers
    pm.min_spare_servers
pm.max_spare_servers
    pm.max_requests
```

Can somebody help?

```
uptime
 13:55:39 up 16:40,  2 users,  load average: 0.13, 0.14, 0.16


free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         24101       3783      20318          0        151       3039
-/+ buffers/cache:        592      23509
Swap:         7811          0       7811
```

I did not change anything in nginx configuration files.

Comment: It sounds like you have done all the correct steps to tune PHP-FPM. What problem are you having?

Comment: The problem is the following lines in php5-fpm.log. Is it normal? [28-Feb-2013 13:21:55] NOTICE: [pool www] child 21868 exited with code 0 after 4171.293476 seconds from start
[28-Feb-2013 13:21:55] NOTICE: [pool www] child 23962 started

Comment: That's normal since you set `pm.max_requests`.

Comment: ok, but what is the purpose of pm.max_requests? By default is not activated.

Comment: As far as I know, it will kill the child and so force the creation of a new child. This will reduce the damage done by memory leaks, as all memory of the child is freed when killed.

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the log `[NOTICE]`: this is informational and **not an error**. 
These are marked `[ERROR]`.

So in short: **nothing to worry about**. It's like your kid telling you they switched off the light in the kitchen.

If it says `[WARNING]` that's something you should take care of, like you did in your first response by increasing the thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

Switch php-fpm to dynamic mode. That way php-fpm automatically decides when to spawn new children.
It is **must have** if you're using and type of opcode caches, because force-killed children increase fragmentation in PHP-APC